# INTELLIJ IDEA How to set artifact same as war under target

Tags: intellij-idea, deployment, war, artifact

When I maven build a project in Intellij. A war is produce under the /target folder.And when I deployed this .war as external source. My apps could run perfectly in local. But when I choose to deploy as artifact: war exploded and drag the project. The application comes strange and seems many files are missing. May I ask how could I set the artifact of the war exploded same as the war file produced at /target folder. I have struggle days and cannot find solutions on web. Is there any way I could set the artifact in war-exploded so that the behavior is same as the war file?

Answer (score 0):

Please check the following: File | Settings | Build, Execution, Deployment | Build Tools | Gradle | Runner | *Delegate IDE build/run actions to gradle*.

Comment: There seems to be a bug here. IntelliJ seems unable to deploy the _exploded_ artifact when delegating build actions to Gradle. The regular WAR file works fine but the exploded artifact is required for recompiling view files without redeploying.